# C++ badly initialized std::set

Tags: c++, std

I have a public variable inside a class, declared as

```
std::set<int> test;
```

and never explicitly initialized. When I try to access it from a shared pointer `c` of an instance of the object:

```
std::set<int>& myset = c->test;
```

I see in the debugger that `myset` is badly initialized: it has both fields `_Myhead` and `_Mysize` null. Could you please explain why that happens?

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). All we can do is guess at what is wrong. For example: perhaps the `c` pointer is not initialized correctly but I can't see how it was declared or initialized.

Comment: It will be default initialized when the enclosing class initialized. Why do you think it's badly initialized? `_Myhead` and `_Mysize` are implementaion details, it might be ok for them to be `null`.

Comment: how do you know its badly initialized? Having _Myhead and _Mysize set to 0 or null sounds reasonable for a default constructed `set` (though i don't know the implementation)

Comment: I know it is badly initialised since when I call begin() on its iterator I get an exception.

Comment: @splinter123 Kind of weird you get an exception since according to cppreference, `std::set::begin` is declared as `noexcept`. It doesn't have any preconditions either

Comment: @splinter123 please show the relevant code and tell us what kind of exception exactly you get, it might be in some other part of your code. As it is we can't really answer your question without more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the pointer was not correctly initialised, although I thought it was.

I got confused since I come from Java where a null pointer would have generated an exception without letting me inspect the object's inner variables, so I ruled out that option too early!

Comment: An uninitialized pointer isn't guaranteed to be null - it is *uninitialized*.

Comment: Yes I knew that, in theory, but still took a long time to realise it in this case since my instincts are still too much Java centric...

Comment: @splinter123 Even if the pointer is NULL, it could still be uninitialized.  If you don't explicitly set that pointer value to NULL, expect it to have any value, even ones you deem as "ok".

Answer (score 1):

You are using std::set<>, and it has own constructor which initialize inner data. So null is OK.

Comment: Not downvoting over a nuisance niggle, but this assumes the containing object `c` is properly initialized, something we cannot be sure of due to the holes in the question. If `c` is bad, all bets are off about the state of `test`.